# PHP/MYSQL - How to detect if it still the same value in a column before an update (codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm a bit ***new*** to MySQL/PHP, please don't be **rude**.

I have a table named "tbl_roguea" which contains columns 
"unitassid", "unitass" and "rankid", "rank". All of that columns are filled up with information like these:

tbl_roguea sample

[image]

Now I have another table named "tbl_rogueb" for counting all of the ranks and where station they are assigned. My method of counting is calling a stored procedure doing **INSERT**. If we are pertaining to the table above:

tbl_rogueb sample

[image]

NOW, whenever I insert a row in tbl_roguea, tbl_rogueb will insert a row(like above), and tbl_roguea will be counted, THAT'S okay. The **problem** is what if I update columns "unitassid", "unitass" and "rankid", "rank" but doesn't change any values. How will I not insert another row in tbl_rogueb if I updated values in tbl_roguea with the same values.

This is the sample code from PHP:

```
public function rogueA_upGet()
    {
        $r_id = $this->input->post('mdl_a_id');
        $r_itemNR = $this->input->post('mdl_a_itemnr');

        $r_rankid = $this->input->post('mdl_a_rank');
        $r_rank = $this->input->post('hdmdl_rank');

        $r_lname = $this->input->post('mdl_a_lname');
        $r_fname = $this->input->post('mdl_a_fname');
        $r_mname = $this->input->post('mdl_a_mname');

        $r_desigid = $this->input->post('mdl_a_desig');
        $r_desig = $this->input->post('hdmdl_off');

        $r_unitassid = $this->input->post('mdl_a_unitass');
        $r_unitass = $this->input->post('hdmdl_uass');

        $r_dgov = $this->input->post('mdl_a_dgs');
        $r_dfir = $this->input->post('mdl_a_dfs');
        $r_lastp = $this->input->post('mdl_a_dlp');
        $r_dpprps = $this->input->post('mdl_a_DPPRPS');
        $r_daodco = $this->input->post('mdl_a_DPOD');
        $r_bday = $this->input->post('mdl_a_bday');
        $r_sa = $this->input->post('mdl_a_stat');

        $r_hitrainid = $this->input->post('mdl_a_hightr');
        $r_hitrain = $this->input->post('hdmdl_hitrain');

        $r_eligid = $this->input->post('mdl_a_elig');
        $r_elig = $this->input->post('hdmdl_elig');

        $r_educatt = $this->input->post('mdl_a_educatt');
        $r_sex = $this->input->post('mdl_a_sex');
        $r_relig = $this->input->post('mdl_a_rel');
        $r_civstat = $this->input->post('mdl_a_civstat');
        $r_add = $this->input->post('mdl_a_add');

        $data = array (
            'rogueA_itemNR' => $r_itemNR,

            'rogueA_rankid' => $r_rankid,
            'rogueA_rank' => $r_rank,

            'rogueA_lname' => $r_lname,
            'rogueA_fname' => $r_fname,
            'rogueA_mname' => $r_mname,

            'rogueA_desigid' => $r_desigid,
            'rogueA_desig' => $r_desig,

            'rogueA_unitass' => $r_unitass,

            'rogueA_dgov' => $r_dgov,
            'rogueA_dfir' => $r_dfir,
            'rogueA_lastp' => $r_lastp,
            'rogueA_dpprps' => $r_dpprps,
            'rogueA_daodco' => $r_daodco,
            'rogueA_bday' => $r_bday,
            'rogueA_sa' => $r_sa,
            'rogueA_educatt' => $r_educatt,

            'rogueA_eligid' => $r_eligid,
            'rogueA_elig' => $r_elig,

            'rogueA_hitrainid' => $r_hitrainid,
            'rogueA_hitrain' => $r_hitrain,

            'rogueA_sex' => $r_sex,
            'rogueA_relig' => $r_relig,
            'rogueA_civstat' => $r_civstat,
            'rogueA_add' => $r_add
            );

        $this->db->where('rogueA_id', $r_id);

            if($this->db->update('tbl_roguea',$data)){
                $this->trackermod->log_rA_update($log_itemNR,$log_comname);

                if($this->db->query('call rogue_A_update("'.$data['rogueA_id'].'","'.$data['rogueA_unitassid'].'")'))
                {
                    return true;
                }else {

                    if($data['rogueA_unitassid']  == '4' || $data['rogueA_unitassid']   == '5')
                        {
                            $this->db->query('call rogue_B_SusaMer("4","Emergency Medical & Rescue Services / Susana Heights Sub-Station");');
                        }
                    else if($data['rogueA_unitassid']  == '1' || $data['rogueA_unitassid']   == '2' ||$data['rogueA_unitassid']   == '3')
                        {
                            $this->db->query('call rogue_B("'.$data['rogueA_unitassid'] .'","'.$data['rogueA_unitass'] .'","'.$data['rogueA_unitassid'] .'");');
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                        $this->db->query('CALL rogue_B_TOTAL();');
                        return true;

                }

            }
        else{
            return $this->db->error();
            return true;
            }
}
```

Sorry for my grammatical errors. Thank you so much for answering my question.

---

edit:
"tbl_rogueb structure"

Field                 Type          Null    Key     Default  Extra

---

rogueB_id             int(11)       NO      PRI     (NULL)   auto_increment
rogueB_unitid         int(11)       YES             (NULL)
rogueB_unit           varchar(100)  YES             (NULL)
rogueB_off_DIR        int(11)       YES             0
rogueB_off_CSUPT      int(11)       YES             0
rogueB_off_SSUPT      int(11)       YES             0
rogueB_off_SUPT       int(11)       YES             0
rogueB_off_CINSP      int(11)       YES             0
rogueB_off_SINSP      int(11)       YES             0
rogueB_off_INSP       int(11)       YES             0
rogueB_off_M          int(11)       YES             0
rogueB_off_F          int(11)       YES             0
rogueB_off_TOTAL      int(11)       YES             0
rogueB_noff_SFO4      int(11)       YES             0
rogueB_noff_SFO3      int(11)       YES             0
rogueB_noff_SFO2      int(11)       YES             0
rogueB_noff_SFO1      int(11)       YES             0
rogueB_noff_FO3       int(11)       YES             0
rogueB_noff_FO2       int(11)       YES             0
rogueB_noff_FO1       int(11)       YES             0
rogueB_noff_M         int(11)       YES             0
rogueB_noff_F         int(11)       YES             0
rogueB_noff_TOTAL     int(11)       YES             0
rogueB_TOTAL_UP       int(11)       YES             0
rogueB_NUP_TOTAL      int(11)       YES             0
rogueB_NUP_M          int(11)       YES             0
rogueB_NUP_F          int(11)       YES             0
rogueB_TOTAL_OVERALL  int(11)       YES             0
rogueB_stamp          varchar(100)  YES             (NULL)

NOTE: I can't add another picture. Sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 0):

As a programmer I can suggest to use option 2. It is a good practice to have all logic inside your application and use database just as a storage. In that case you can easily change database type to use with your application just by changing database type in application/config/database.php.

Generally, if you choose option 2 you could add status, or creation_date/deletion_date columns in your sql table and base your logic on those values. This is some kind of versioning, and a lot to do but you can make it reusable and have benefits from that part of code in other parts of your application.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Siniša.
Maybe I'll try to fortify my code later. But it is good to know your way of programming. For me, I think putting those codes will have more server traffic than putting it on my database. Don't you think?

Comment: Maybe a little but that's negligible. But there's one more elegant solution,  I forgot to mention last time. You can use Codeigniter validation class (if you're using Codeigniter). Here's example: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#cascading-rules.

Comment: Yes! I'm using CI right now! Correct me if what I think is wrong, 
I'll use `$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');` 
The **is_unique** is what I need, right? @Siniša

Comment: Yes, is_unique[table_name.column_name]  is what you need. That way all the checks is handled by the framework. If you're not familiar with CI, there is good tutorial series Codeigniter from scratch, for Codeigniter v1 I think.There's minor changes in syntax and class names but you can get picture how to use built in features of codeigniter.